# jquery drag and drop not working with load()

Tags: php, jquery

I have coded the drag and drop functionality in separate file. it s working fine.

I load this file while clicking the button.

```
$( "#sch_list" ).load( 'test.php' );
```

But it is not working. If i directly paste the content in the div sch_list. Its working fine.

What is wrong here?

my test.php code is : [refer the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RqTz9/)

In my main file i have the content as 
included http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js file

```
<div class="scroll-pane" style="height: 438px;" id="sch_list" >

        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `.load()` function is a shorthand for an AJAX call to load content into a section of the page. You'll need to call any functions to initialize/configure plugins on that new content after it has loaded.

```
$('#sch_list').load('test.php', function() {
    // initialise drag and drop on the new contents of #sch_list here
});
```

Or use a named function that can be called in multiple places (DOM ready, in response to the AJAX calls response, etc):

```
function initDnD() {
    // initialise drag and drop here
}

$('#sch_list').load('test.php', initDnD);
```

Comment: What you mean by initialise. I am not familiar with jquery. Shall i call any function inside this.

Comment: @SamHanson In your jsFiddle you're calling `$('#list ul').sortable(...);` when the DOM is ready to add the ability to drag/drop those elements. However, if you use `.load()` those elements won't exist any longer, so you need to call that `sortable` function again after the new content has been added to the DOM.